# The webpage at localhost might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new address

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I am currently developing website and sometimes when ever I reload my page browser giving me error "The webpage at localhost might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new address." It occurs when I add a lot of javascript and css animation in index.php. My question is what is the cause of this error?and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Check your browser's developer tools to see what's actually going on, as far as a response code from the server.

Comment: Is your webserver running?

Comment: Hi sir Brad and ceejay Thank you for your quick response. Yes I am using wamp server right now and when I clear cached files the history and refresh the page that's the time the error occurs. but if the files and images is already stored in cached the page is working fine. my question is what is the cause of that error?

Answer (score 0):

This because your application router doesnt fetch ( for example react-router-dom doesnt fetch)